# Can't connect to host mongodb from homestead

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, laravel-5, homestead

I have a laravel 5.2 project on homestead 7 which works with mysql and mongodb, I have configured it to connect to host (my mac AMPPS) mysql and mongodb servers.

mysql is connected successfully but I can't connect to host mongodb from homestead.

when I try to connect to host mongodb server from homestead using mongo command I get below error :

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ mongo 192.168.10.1:27017/admin
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.18
connecting to: 192.168.10.1:27017/admin
2018-01-29T13:18:36.967+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 192.168.10.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2018-01-29T13:18:36.968+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 192.168.10.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:231:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

as you can see my host ip address is `192.168.10.1` and homestead ip address is `192.168.10.10`.

And whenever I try to connect to mongodb from laravel mongodb driver I get below error message :

```
ConnectionTimeoutException in Collection.php line 174:
No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection refused calling ismaster on '192.168.10.1:27017']
```

FYI : I used [This](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/master/scripts/install-mongo.sh) shell script to install mongodb and it's driver on homestead 7 with php 7.1

Any suggestion how to fix this ?

Comment: You can ignore the Laravel part for now, since you can't connect to the command line. Start with the basic troubleshooting: Is the mongodb service running? Is it running inside of homestead or outside? If outside, can you connect to it in any other manner?

Comment: @aynber I have this project on linux workstation which is working well, but on my Mac I have this problem, mongodb as I said above is running on host which is my Mac, and I want to connect to it from homestead which is running on vagrant vm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to edit host `/etc/mongodb.conf` and set `bind-ip` to `0.0.0.0`

```
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
```

remember to restart mongodb server, then I connected to the host mongodb server.